# R data frame update entire column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this code, which is intended to create a data frame that will hold the performance matrix of several classification models:

```
eval_table <- data.frame(norm_method_1=c("","","","",""),norm_method_2=c("","","","",""),norm_method_3=c("","","","",""),norm_method_4=c("","","","",""),norm_method_5=c("","","","",""),norm_method_6=c("","","","",""),norm_method_7=c("","","","",""),norm_method_8=c("","","","",""))
    rownames(eval_table) <- c("Log. Model Coeff","Log. Model Confusion Matrix","Log. Model AUC","Linear Modl Coeff","Linear Model overfit ratio")

    col <- list(mnm_coef,cm,auc,lm_summary$coefficients,lm_summary$training_testing_error_ratio)
    eval_table[,c("norm_method_1")] <- col
```

When trying to update the first column of the data frame (last row) with a list of 5 element that I prepared in advance (data frame have 5 rows) I get the following error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , c("norm_method_1"), value = list( : 
  replacement element 1 is a matrix/data frame of 2 rows, need 5
```

Any idea why ?

UPDATE:

```
dim(col)
NULL
str(col)
> str(col)
List of 5
 $ : num [1:2, 1:30] 21.436 40.828 -0.785 0.54 -1.375 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "2" "3"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:30] "(Intercept)" "is_top_rated_listing1" "seller_is_top_rated_seller" "is_auto_pay1" ...
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ positive: NULL
  ..$ table   : 'table' int [1:3, 1:3] 414 73 433 101 329 1186 147 60 10546
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ Prediction: chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
  .. .. ..$ Reference : chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
  ..$ overall : Named num [1:7] 0.849 0.402 0.843 0.856 0.809 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "Accuracy" "Kappa" "AccuracyLower" "AccuracyUpper" ...
  ..$ byClass : num [1:3, 1:8] 0.45 0.204 0.981 0.98 0.989 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "Class: 1" "Class: 2" "Class: 3"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:8] "Sensitivity" "Specificity" "Pos Pred Value" "Neg Pred Value" ...
  ..$ dots    : list()
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "confusionMatrix"
 $ :Classes 'auc', 'numeric'  atomic [1:1] 0.592
  .. ..- attr(*, "partial.auc")= logi FALSE
  .. ..- attr(*, "percent")= logi FALSE
  .. ..- attr(*, "roc")=List of 8
  .. .. ..$ percent      : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..$ sensitivities: num [1:1021] 1 0.998 0.998 0.998 0.996 ...
  .. .. ..$ specificities: num [1:1021] 0 0 0.00151 0.00302 0.00302 ...
  .. .. ..$ thresholds   : num [1:1021] -Inf 0.358 0.359 0.36 0.361 ...
  .. .. ..$ direction    : chr "<"
  .. .. ..$ cases        : num [1:462] 0.51 0.727 0.725 0.667 0.667 ...
  .. .. ..$ controls     : num [1:662] 0.903 0.967 0.756 0.966 0.981 ...
  .. .. ..$ fun.sesp     :function (thresholds, controls, cases, direction)  
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "roc"
 $ : num [1:28, 1:4] 3.18 3.49 -3.55 -1.16 4.1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:28] "(Intercept)" "is_top_rated_listing1" "seller_is_top_rated_seller" "is_auto_pay1" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Estimate" "Std. Error" "t value" "Pr(>|t|)"
 $ : num 0.819
>
```

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could elaborate: my list has 5 elements and so does my dataframe has 5 rows. How can I update the first column with the 5 elements list such that each list element will be written to a different row

Comment: Well, the error IMHO says that `mnm_coef` is a matrix (or data frame) with 2 rows. So what you are trying doesn't fit at all. However, noone can say for sure since you didn't provide an reproducible example (ready to copy/paste and run without errors others than yours).

Answer (score 0):

If you get in a situation like this you need to check that the size of your data is what you think it is.  Use

```
length(col)
```

to verify your assumptions about col.  The message is saying the sizes are not compatible.

If they were, the assignment would work - for example,

```
col <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
eval_table[,c("norm_method_1")] <- col
```

In this case, `length(col)` returns 5.

Another useful command is `str` - i.e. `str(eval_table)` and `str(col)`.  This will help you see size incompatibilities.

In this case, your first element is a matrix.  So we could mock this up like so:

```
mat <- matrix(1,2)
col <- list(mat, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Then you would see the error you got.  To overcome this, build your list with the first element of the matrix as your first element, and build it as a vector:

```
 col <- c(mat[1][1], 2,3, 4,5)
```

Then this works:

```
eval_table[,c("norm_method_1")] <- col
```

Comment: The length is 5 and it still doesn't work (same error). On the other hand : eval_table$norm_method_1 <- col                does work. Any idea how I can access the data frame by the first (and currently faulty) approach since the column name changes

Comment: What does `str(col)` show? Can you use `dim(col)` ?

Comment: see UPDATE above in the Q